# Open file containing tuples in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I open a file in python containing a tuple with tuples inside without altering it.

My problema is that when I do `file.read()` it becomes a string and the spaces between tuples dissapear. I will receive sth like this:

```
e=(((2,), (3,), (2,), (2, 2), (2,)), ((2,), (1, 2), (2,), (3,), (3,)))
```

How do I open it without modifying it?

Comment: Show the file content and your code for reading it.

Comment: the file is for exemple: (((3,),(5,),(3,1),(2,1),(3,3,4),(2,2,7),(6,1,1),(4,2,2),(1,1),(3,1),(6,),(2,7),(6,3,1),(1,2,2,1,1),(4,1,1,3),(4,2,2),(3,3,1),(3,3),(3,),(2,1)),((2,),(1,2),(2,3),(2,3),(3,1,1),(2,1,1),(1,1,1,2,2),(1,1,3,1,3),(2,6,4),(3,3,9,1),(5,3,2),(3,1,2,2),(2,1,7),(3,3,2),(2,4),(2,1,2),(2,2,1),(2,2), (1,),(1,))) -- >( "jogo_fig2.txt")  . I did: f= open(cc,'r') 
    f=f.read()

Comment: A file is a string.  That's what you get when you don't modify it.  You have to write code to convert it back to a tuple.  `ast.literal_eval()` can do that.

Comment: I will try iy thanks for your help

Comment: Easy: Write your file in a better format. You are paying for your laziness when you were writing the file. It's a lot simpler to write out an easy-to-parse format than to read a dump of your data structure robustly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply writing or pasting the python code to a tuple won't work. This way the tuple you earlier had becomes a string and loses its functionality. There is a module `pickle` included in the Python Standard Library which can be used for this purpose. Pickle simply converts the data into a bytestring with the `pickle.dumps` function which you can write to a file and you can simply read the file and insert the string into the `pickle.loads` function which will help you get back the tuple in original form.
I am including an example below:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> s = (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13)
>>> data = pickle.dumps(s)
>>> data
b'\x80\x03(K\x02K\x03K\x05K\x07K\x0bK\rtq\x00.'
>>> print(pickle.loads(data))
(2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13)
```

I hope you have got an idea about how this works.

Comment: Thanks for your help!I  really appreciate it!. I will try it now

Answer (score 0):

Example to convert a tuple-like string back to a tuple:

```
>>> e = '(((3,),(5,),(3,1),(2,1),(3,3,4),(2,2,7),(6,1,1),(4,2,2),(1,1),(3,1),(6,),(2,7),(6,3,1),(1,2,2,1,1),(4,1,1,3),(4
,2,2),(3,3,1),(3,3),(3,),(2,1)),((2,),(1,2),(2,3),(2,3),(3,1,1),(2,1,1),(1,1,1,2,2),(1,1,3,1,3),(2,6,4),(3,3,9,1),(5,3,2
),(3,1,2,2),(2,1,7),(3,3,2),(2,4),(2,1,2),(2,2,1),(2,2), (1,),(1,)))'
>>> type(e)
<class 'str'>

>>> import ast
>>> t = ast.literal_eval(e)
>>> type(t)
<class 'tuple'>
>>> t
(((3,), (5,), (3, 1), (2, 1), (3, 3, 4), (2, 2, 7), (6, 1, 1), (4, 2, 2), (1, 1), (3, 1), (6,), (2, 7), (6, 3, 1), (1, 2
, 2, 1, 1), (4, 1, 1, 3), (4, 2, 2), (3, 3, 1), (3, 3), (3,), (2, 1)), ((2,), (1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 3), (3, 1, 1), (2, 1,
1), (1, 1, 1, 2, 2), (1, 1, 3, 1, 3), (2, 6, 4), (3, 3, 9, 1), (5, 3, 2), (3, 1, 2, 2), (2, 1, 7), (3, 3, 2), (2, 4), (2
, 1, 2), (2, 2, 1), (2, 2), (1,), (1,)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I aprecciate it